# DataFrame groupby and divide by group sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter, back-testing

In order to build stock portfolios for a backtest I am trying to get the market capitalization (me) weight of each stock within its portfolio. For test purposes I built the following DataFrame of price and return observations. Every day I am assigning the stocks to quantiles based on price and all stocks in the same quantile that day will be in one portfolio:

```
d = {'date' : ['202211', '202211', '202211','202211', '202212', '202212', '202212', '202212'],
     'price' : [1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 2, 1.5, 1],
     'shrs' : [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y%m%d')
df["me"] = df['price'] * df['shrs']
df['rank'] = df.groupby('date')['price'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 2, labels=range(1,3), duplicates='drop'))
df
```

```
            price  shrs     me rank
date                               
2022-01-01    1.0   100  100.0    1
2022-01-01    1.2   100  120.0    1
2022-01-01    1.3   100  130.0    2
2022-01-01    1.5   100  150.0    2
2022-01-02    1.7   100  170.0    2
2022-01-02    2.0   100  200.0    2
2022-01-02    1.5   100  150.0    1
2022-01-02    1.0   100  100.0    1
```

In the next step I am grouping by 'date' and 'rank' and divide each observation's market cap by the sum of the groups market cap in order to obtain the stocks weight in the portfolio:

```
df['weight'] = df.groupby(['date', 'rank'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x['me'] / x['me'].sum()).sort_index()
print(df)
```

```
            price  shrs     me rank    weight
date                                         
2022-01-01    1.0   100  100.0    1  0.454545
2022-01-01    1.2   100  120.0    1  0.545455
2022-01-01    1.3   100  130.0    2  0.464286
2022-01-01    1.5   100  150.0    2  0.535714
2022-01-02    1.7   100  170.0    2  0.600000
2022-01-02    2.0   100  200.0    2  0.400000
2022-01-02    1.5   100  150.0    1  0.459459
2022-01-02    1.0   100  100.0    1  0.540541
```

Now comes the flaw. On my test df this works perfectly fine. However on the real data (DataFrame with shape 160000 x 21) the calculations take endless and I always have to interrupt the Jupyter Kernel at some point. Is there a more efficient way to do this? What am I missing?
Interestingly I am using the same code as some colleagues on similar DataFrames and for them it takes seconds only.

Comment: Wrong dupe, reopened. Bottleneck is `df['rank'] = df.groupby('date')['price'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 2, labels=range(1,3), duplicates='drop'))` - if call `qcut` for many groups it is very slow. My answer only a bit increase performance

Comment: Actually the initial answer was great. I never had an issue with ```df['rank'] = df.groupby('date')['price'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 2, labels=range(1,3), duplicates='drop'))``` line.

Comment: Ok, answer was undeleted. Let me know if helped.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` for new `Series` and use it for divide `me` column:

```
df['weight'] = df['me'].div(df.groupby(['date', 'rank'])['me'].transform('sum'))
```

Comment: great solution, works really fast!

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most elegant solution, but if you run into performance issue you can try to split it into multiple parts, but storing the groupped value of `me` in a Series and then merge it back

```
temp = df.groupby(['date', 'rank'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x['me'].sum())
temp = temp.reset_index(name='weight')
df = df.merge(temp, on=['date', 'rank'])
df['weight'] = df['me'] / df['weight']
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df
```

which should lead to the output:

```
    price   shrs    me  rank    weight
date                    
2022-01-01  1.0     100     100.0   1   0.454545
2022-01-01  1.2     100     120.0   1   0.545455
2022-01-01  1.3     100     130.0   2   0.464286
2022-01-01  1.5     100     150.0   2   0.535714
2022-01-02  1.7     100     170.0   2   0.459459
2022-01-02  2.0     100     200.0   2   0.540541
2022-01-02  1.5     100     150.0   1   0.600000
2022-01-02  1.0     100     100.0   1   0.400000
```